# How to not not display html if variable isn't there?

Tags: php

I have a site that has different features but I do not want a feature to show if it does not have a variable assigned to it.

For example, my product has a featured list like this:

```
<h3>Specifications</h3>
<ul>
    <li class="element element-text first">
        <strong>Manufacturer: </strong><?php echo $manufactuer;?>
    </li>
    <li class="element element-text">
        <strong>Model #: </strong><?php echo $model;?>
    </li>
    <li class="element element-text">
        <strong>Previously Ran: </strong><?php echo $ran;?>
    </li>
    <li class="element element-text last">
</ul>
```

On the front end, I don't want the `Model` line displayed if that doesn't have a variable assigned to it.

Comment: Please google for `isset()` and `empty()`.

Comment: Please do not post answer inside the question body. Also please make sure to be concise when wording your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```php
<?php if (isset($model) && !empty($model)) : ?>
<li class="element element-text">
  <strong>Model #: </strong>
  <?php echo $model;?>
</li>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: It is still showing "Previously Ran:" when there is no variable.

Comment: Yes, this example is only for the Model item, you should do the same for each variable.
Each <li>.....</li> segment should be inside a php block like the one i put there.

Comment: Ok that means the variable exists but it's empty, 
You can modify each if like this
<?php if (isset($model) AND !empty($model)) : ?>
I updated the code above.

Comment: Worked like a charm. I didnt know you could use both isset and empty. I was trying it with one or the other. I sure appreciate your time and knowledge.

Comment: Thanks. You can use only empty(), but sometimes it throws warnings if the variable isn't set, so using both this way is error free ;)

Comment: Done, I thought I did it yesterday. Thanks Again,

Answer (score 1):

You need to use JavaScript to write the HTML when you start the page. You probably want something like this (make sure you have a script called JQuery, you can find it online):

```
$.ajax({ url: '/my/site.php',
    datatype: "JSON", /* Personal preference */
    type: 'get',
    cache: false,
    success: function(data) {
        alert(output);
        if(data[1] != null){
            document.getElementById('ID').innerHTML = "<li>" + data[1] + "</li>";
        } else {
            console.log("nothing found");
        }
    }
});
```

You may need to adjust things a bit for your particular code writing, but this would be the approach I think you need. In general, dynamic elements (ones that are not static i.e. ones that respond to stuff outside the HTML) need to dealt with in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this

```
  <?php if(isset($model)): ?>
          <li class="element element-text">
          <strong>Model #: </strong><?php echo $model;?>
        </li>
  <?php  endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do,

```
<?php echo (!empty($model))?$model:'';?>
```

Read up on: [empty](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php), and [ternary operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary)

Answer (score 0):

Full code like this:

```
<h3>Specifications</h3>
        <ul>
            <?php if(isset($manufacturer) && !empty($manufacturer)): ?>
                <li class="element element-text first">
                    <strong>Manufacturer: </strong><?php echo $manufactuer;?>
                </li>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <?php if(isset($model) && !empty($model)): ?>
                <li class="element element-text">
                    <strong>Model #: </strong><?php echo $model;?>
                </li>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <?php if(isset($ran) && !empty($ran)): ?>
                <li class="element element-text">
                    <strong>Previously Ran: </strong><?php echo $ran;?>
                </li>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <li class="element element-text last"></li>
       </ul>
```

Comment: PS You also forgot to close last <li> tag on your code